# How to save the resized state of textarea via jQuery and localStorage

Tags: jquery, resize, textarea, local-storage

Most modern browsers have resize handles on textarea elements. The problem is that they don't automatically remember where you left them from visit to visit.

I'd like to enable my app with this functionality. To do this, I'm planning to utilize jQuery (to bind the textarea resize to a function) along with the html5 localStorage object in order to write the height and width of a textarea element to a localStorage item.

I need to bind the localStorage write event to the equivalent jQuery event that signals the textarea has been resized.

What are the relevant jQuery methods to bind the function to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only bind to the window's resize event, not a textarea's. What you'll need to do is create a polling function to listen to the size and if it changes, update.

Something like this:

```
var checkSize = setInterval(function(){ 
    var $text = $('#myTextArea');
    if (localStorage && localStorage.myTextAreaWidth) {
        if ($text.width() != localStorage.myTextAreaWidth) {
            localStorage.myTextAreaWidth  = $text.width();
        }
        if ($text.height() != localStorage.myTextAreaHeight) {
            localStorage.myTextAreaHeight = $text.height();
        }
    } else {
        localStorage.myTextAreaWidth  = $text.width();
        localStorage.myTextAreaHeight = $text.height();
    }
}, 1000);

$(function(){
    var $text = $('#myTextArea');
    if (localStorage && localStorage.myTextAreaWidth) {
        $text.css({
            width  : localStorage.myTextAreaWidth  + 'px',
            height : localStorage.myTextAreaHeight + 'px'
        });
    } 
});
```

**Here's a demo**:  http://jsfiddle.net/TDKpr/

You can see it's working by resizing in the fiddle, closing the tab, opening up a new tab, revisiting the fiddle and the textarea maintains the size you picked from last time.

Comment: Interesting, would this impact page performance in any noticeable way?

Comment: Not likely unless you're polling every 10ms or something crazy.

Comment: Resetting the size with `css(...)` didn't work correctly for me. It kept making the text areas smaller and smaller with each refreshing. Using `$text.height(localStorage.myTextAreaHeight)` etc. instead has solved this problem. (Obviously, CSS counts in some border or padding or whatever into the height, while `height()` doesn't.)

Comment: The fiddle link still works for me in Chrome. What browser are you using where it's showing unexpected results @ddekany ?

Comment: @AlienWebguy I haven't tried this on the fiddle, but on a page that uses YUI pure.css, with Firefox. I guess this depends on the styling of the text area (borders, padding and such), rather than on the browser. Anyway, certainly it's safer to use the same mechanism to write the dimensions than that you have used to read them.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to use localStorage this could be helpful for you :

### html

```
<textarea class="rz" id="txt_id_1" cols="40" rows="5">resize test</textarea>
```

### jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//on load set the default or history size
var track_ta='txt_id_1';

initSize();

function initSize(){
   var ta_size=localStorage.getItem(track_ta);
   //default size
   if(ta_size==null) ta_size={width:'200px', height:'50px'};
   else ta_size=JSON.parse(ta_size);
   $('#'+track_ta).css(ta_size);
}

//keep the latest in the local storage
$("textarea.rz").resizable({
    resize: function() {  
       var sizeHistory=JSON.stringify({width:this.style.width,height:this.style.height});
       localStorage.setItem(track_ta,sizeHistory);
    }
});
});
```

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/PPZEK/ , just resize and reload the page.

You can generalize the concept for all textarea. As I see default resize-handler for textarea does not provide any reisize events obviously we have to use jquery resize.

Comment: +1 I like that its not a polling solution, but 2 things you should mention, it requires jquery-ui and it removes chrome/ff default resize handles.